# How to calculate date time in one field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table below named transaction_detail

```
 id_transd | id_trans | id_cust | inputtime           |
 1         | 1        | 1       | 2013-04-15 16:55:58 | 
 2         | 1        | 1       | 2013-05-15 16:55:58 | 
 3         | 1        | 1       | 2013-06-15 16:55:58 |
 4         | 2        | 2       | 2013-06-15 16:55:58 |
```

I want to get the amount of the inputtime (type : datetime) which have the same id_cust. I've done with the date, but I don't know how to calculate the time. This is my sql syntax to calculate the date :

```
select (date(max(inputtime)) - date (min(inputtime))) as total from transaction_detail where id_cust = '$idp'
```

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks before.

Comment: Can you tell how would the output will look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in this website this might help what you need.
http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Answer (score 0):

Use TIMESTAMPDIFF function to get difference between two datetime values in units you want.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Units could be: MICROSECOND (microseconds), SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR.